# How to build .exe from TeamCity Server

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, teamcity-9.0

I've been trying to build an .exe file directly from my Mercurial Repositories using Team City CI.

I want to have a downloadable .exe generated by TeamCity on each build.

Is this possible, and what tool would you recommend for this purpose?

I'm using TeamCity 9x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just setup your TeamCity Project to Build your Solution/Project, then specify to output the Built .exe as an artifact.

To do this, in your Build Project "General Settings", under artifacts paths, specify the following.

MyProject/bin/*.exe => dist

Where MyProject/bin/*.exe is the relative path in the checkout directory to where the exe is built.

or, target any .exe in your build folder with....

**/*.exe => dist

When you run this Build, TeamCity will look in your bin folder specified and take any built .exe in the root of the bin folder and place it in a dist folder in an artifact.

You will end up with some artifacts which you can access by clicking the Arrow. This will show you the dist folder containing your .exe which you can click to download.

Hope this helps